# How to read the values stored in a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

Here I am trying to implement a stack, where only opening braces from a string will be filtered out and stored in an array. The code I wrote stored the values in `stackArr` array. But whenever I attempt to print out the array, my code fails. It doesn't give any specific error message, it just fails to execute.

**I think problem is in the following portion:**

```
i = 0;
while(stackArr[i] != '\0')
{
    printf("%c ",stackArr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

**Full code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char braces[10];
    char stackArr[10];
    int front = -1,rear = -1,size = 10;
    gets(braces);
    checkValidate(&braces,&stackArr,&front,&rear,size);
}

void checkValidate(char *braces,char *stackArr,int *front,int *rear,int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(braces[i] != '\0')
    {
        if((braces[i] == '(') || (braces[i] =='{') ||  (braces[i] =='['))
        {
             push(braces[i],&stackArr,&front,&rear,size);
        }
        i++;
    }
    //print(&front,&rear,size,*stackArr);
    i = 0;
    while(stackArr[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c ",stackArr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void push (char val,char *stackArr,int *front,int *rear,int size)
{
    if(isFull(*front,*rear,size))
    {
         printf("your string is larger that valid size\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(isEmpty(*front,*rear))
        {
            *front = 0;
        }
        *rear = (*rear+1) % size;

        stackArr[*rear] = val;
        /*printf("%d ",*rear);
        printf("%c",stackArr[*rear]);
        printf("\n");*/
    }
}

int isEmpty(int front,int rear)
{
    if(front == -1 && rear == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(int front,int rear,int size)
{
    if(front == 0 && rear == size -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void print(int *front,int *rear,int size,char *arr)
{
    int i;
    for(i = *rear;i != *front; i = (i-1)% size)
    {
        printf("%c\n",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%c\n",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: What data do you supply as input?

Comment: The expression `&braces` does *not* give you a pointer to a `char`, it gives you a pointer to an *array* of ten `char` elements. Very different. And something the compiler should have caught for you if you only remembered to create a function prototype declaration before you called the function. As it is now you should still get warnings though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight supplied a user input like "[ { } ] "

Comment: Also, don't use `gets`. Ever. It's dangerous, has been obsoleted since the C99 standard, and removed from the standard completely in the C11 standard.

Comment: Your codes doesn't compile with a modern compiler. Compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Side note: you may as well replace your entire print-loop with `printf("%s",stackArr);`.

Comment: That `print` function at the end is not used, and should be destroyed ASAP. inderection on `front` and `rear` for _no reason_? Seriously: it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code must produce a lot of warnings on compile, because the functions that you call lack forward declarations. Hence, compiler *assumes* that all functions that you call have parameters of type `int`, and that they also return an `int`. Since your functions take pointers instead, the calls of your functions result in undefined behavior, which is likely leading to a crash.

```
// Put these declarations in front of main
void checkValidate(char *braces,char *stackArr,int *front,int *rear,int size);
void push (char val,char *stackArr,int *front,int *rear,int size);
int isEmpty(int front,int rear);
int isFull(int front,int rear,int size);
void print(int *front,int *rear,int size,char *arr);
```

Adding forward declarations should fix this problem. In addition, you need to replace the now-deprecated `gets` call with a call to `fgets`, which is safe from buffer overruns.

You also pass pointers to arrays to functions that expect pointers to character. You need to remove `&` in front of `braces` and `stackArr`. Turn on compiler warnings to see all places where this needs to be done.

Finally, your code expects `stackArr` to be null-terminated, but you never set its elements to zeros. Add `char stackArr[10] = {0}` to initialize the array to zeros.

Comment: i  added that but that didn't fix my problem :(

Comment: Alternatively, move `int main(void)` to the bottom of the file, and define the functions in the correct order

Comment: @AL-zami Please take a look at the edit. This gets you [some output](http://ideone.com/S49EJa), not sure if that's what you wanted to see, but at least it's no longer crashing.

Comment: thnx..i understand the problems now...u must be a wizard of c i guess :D